# how to change text automatically in compose when button click

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun Counter(name: Int) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello ${name}!2" + name,
        fontSize = 18.sp,
    )
}
```

When the increase button is clicked name value increase +1 however, text ui doesn't change.
How can I make this ui change automatically.

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable somewhere to track the count and have it incremented when a button is clicked.

```
@Composable
fun Counter(name: Int) {
    var counter by state { name }

    Column {
        Text(
            text = "Hello ${counter}!",
            fontSize = 18.sp,
        )
        Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
            Text("Increase")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean when parameter increase. Counter(1) -> Counter(2)

Comment: I save variable at the viewmodel so this cannot be a solution for me.